# Thunderbolt dock not recognized

Tags: 18.04, drivers, kernel, thunderbolt

I am running 18.04LTS on a dell precision 7540. I have been using my Thunderbolt dock with it quite happily for about 9 months.

But this week, I updated some drivers (nvidia) and upgraded the kernel. Once I rebooted, my dock is no longer being recognized. Neither power, nor mouse, nor keyboard, nor displays attached to the dock are recognized.

Symptoms:

- `modprobe thunderbolt` returns no output.
- `boltctl list` returns no output.
- `boltd` is running.

`Settings->Devices->Thunderbolt` shows: "No devices attached"

However, `lspci -tv` yields:

```
+-1c.0-[04-6e]----00.0-[05-6e]--+-00.0-[06]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
|                               +-01.0-[07-39]--
|                               +-02.0-[3a]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
|                               \-04.0-[3b-6e]--
```

I have double checked my BIOS settings a couple times, but since things worked before my latest updates, I don't think this is related.

I have tried rolling back my kernel version to 5.4.0-48. (I had upgraded to 5.4.0-62).

I checked `dmesg` and I noticed one usb error: `usb 1-2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1`, but not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by going to settings > privacy > thunderbolt, and then selecting unlock.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see "thunderbolt" under "settings > privacy" on my system.